Unit Test pipeline - Django Unit tests
I am working on a django project and it has 20+ apps in it which means I have to run tests of 20+ apps which includes 3000+ tests. So I decided to make subjobs in my pipeline and now running 20 jobs for the  unit tests on commit. But the issue is that when more than 1 developer commits and tests runs for both, pipeline get stucks. Pipeline runners are registered on a VM of 32 CPU cores and 24 GB of RAM. CPU utilization becomes 100% and jobs stuck(deadlock).
How can I optimize my pipeline subjobs so that if multiple devs work it didnt stuck.
 unit_test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - changes:
      - backend/
  tags:
    - workstream-unit-test
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - APP_NAME:
          - apps.app1
          - apps.app2
          - .
          - apps.app20
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - COVERAGE_FILENAME=$(echo "$APP_NAME" | tr '.' '_')_coverage.xml
    - coverage run --source=$APP_NAME ./manage.py test $APP_NAME --settings=hrdb.test_settings --keepdb --noinput
    - coverage xml -i -o $COVERAGE_FILENAME
    - coverage report -m --fail-under=90 --skip-covered
  coverage: '/(?i)TOTAL.*? (100(?:\.0+)?%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?%)$/'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 hour
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$APP_NAME_coverage.xml`

I am expecting to use same VM with same specs but the pipeline optimization so that the pipeline process runs smoothly
